# Who is the demon who saved Cell from being killed from Vegeta?

Tags: dragon-ball-manga, dragon-ball-heroes

In chapter #4 of the Super Dragon Ball Heroes manga a demon with a hammer appears and saves Cell from being killed by Vegeta. Who is this demon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character you're referring to is [*Gravy*](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Gravy), one of the strongest wizards during the foundation of the dark realm. He was a wizard in the Heavenly Realm. He basically joins Demigara and Putine to Fight against Chronoa(The Supreme Kai of time).

[image: Gravy]